# manipulate a string in django to show past/future tense

Tags: django, string, datetime

I'm looking for a way to manipulate a string depending if it's in the past or the future, so I want to:

Test to see if it's now or in the future
   add an "s" to the string
Test to see if it's in the past
   add a "d" to the string

I know this has come up before, but didn't find it in a search.

Thanks!

Wendy

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's something within django that does this, but you can categorize the tense of a word using [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org).  For examples, see the parts of speech tagger in [chapter 5](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/book/ch05.html#tab-simplified-tagset) of the [NLTK book](http://www.nltk.org/book) (free online).

Comment: Thanks, this looks really interesting.  I wound up using datetime.date.today() and was able to use  => in my template logic to deliver the right word, but I'm going to delve into the book, looks like a great resource.